# Sprites attached to scene without intention

Tags: android, andengine

I have three `TextureRegions` that are created like this:

```
mBackgroundTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(mMenuTextureAtlas, pActivity, "menu_background.png", 0, 0);
mPlayBtnTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(mMenuTextureAtlas, pActivity, "play_btn.png", 50, 100);
mExitBtnTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(mMenuTextureAtlas, pActivity, "exit_btn.png", 50, 200);
```

I also have corresponding sprites for each `TextureRegion` which are created like this:

```
mBackgroundSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, mBackgroundTextureRegion, mBufferObjectManager);
mPlayBtnSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, mPlayBtnTextureRegion, mBufferObjectManager);
mExitBtnSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, mExitBtnTextureRegion, mBufferObjectManager);
```

When I attach `mBackgroundSprite` to a scene like this:

```
mScene.attachChild(mBackgroundSprite);
```

I would expect only `mBackgroundTextureRegion` to appear on the scene (i.e. "menu_background.png") but in reality all three `TextureRegions` appear (i.e. `mPlayBtnTextureRegion` and `mExitBtnTextureRegion` appear too in their location as well, (50,100) and (50,200) respectively).

My questions are:

A. Why does this happen? (does it have something to do with using the same Texture for all TextureRegions?)

B. What is the correct way to make only one TextureRegion appear on a scene?

Answer (score 0):

No this has nothing to do with the texture atlas. This is the correct way of doing it more or less. Nothing should be shown on the screen unless they are attached as a child to something (scene or engine). If you need more straightforward help please upload the part of your code that you are loading the sprite.